# Create foreign key to part of composite primary key

Tags: foreign-keys, composite-key

I am trying to create a FK using a composite PK and here are the details that I want to achieve.

```
Table -A
Column A1
Column A2
Primary key (A1, A2).

Table -B
Column B1 Primary key.
Column B2
FK (B2) References A(A1).
```

When I try to do this I am getting some errors.

Questions:
First of all is this possible? If yes, then how do I can create it?

Comment: Give your code and the error messages. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is declared when some columns' subrow values always appear as some unique (PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE NON NULL) columns' subrow values. A (A1) is not unique so you cannot be wanting a FK to it. What is the constraint on your tables that you do want? If A (A1) is unique, declare it so. If then B (B2) is always in that column declare FK B (B2) referencing A (A1). If A (A1) is not unique and you want B (B2) to be in it then you must constrain by other means such as triggers. Or maybe you should have a different schema.